# Group by Rollup: Visualforce Remoting Exception: Too many query rows: 1000001

Tags: governorlimits, javascript-remoting, aggregate, read-only, group-by-rollup

I have 557,029 Foo objects in my org.  I want to count how many of each kind of picklist value there are within these:

Type 1 - 100,000
Type 2 - 60,000
Type 3 - 40,000
Type N - N

I thought I could do this with a [@ReadOnly @RemoteAction](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_readonly_context_methodlevel.htm) and [Javascript Remoting](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm), as well as the [GROUP BY ROLLUP(picklist api name) option](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_rollup.htm).

Code:

```
@Readonly
    @RemoteAction
    global static Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> loadObjectValues(){

        Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> res = new Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>();
        res.put('Bar__c', new Map<String, Integer>());

        List<AggregateResult> ar = [Select Bar__c, COUNT(Name) total from Foo__c WHERE Bar__c != null GROUP BY ROLLUP(Bar__c)];

        for(AggregateResult a: ar){

            res.get('Bar__c').put((String)a.get('Bar__c'), (Integer)a.get('total'));
        }

        return res;
    }
```

This gives me 7 Rows, and it explodes with this remoting message:

```
Visualforce Remoting Exception: Too many query rows: 1000001
```

Now, I know that the number of query rows for AggregateFunction are the number of records that were "touched" but not necessary returned, but if I only have 557k records, how can it count the same record twice?  I'd like to know the exact calculation it's doing (the debug logs tell me nothing) so I can know if this is possible or not.

EDIT:

See Query Plan Tool screenshot below

[image]

EDIT 2:
Experimenting with other records, it appears that the number of query rows returned is always double what it should be.  In other words, it is 557029 * 2 > 1kk.  I can't find any mention of that in the docs, maybe a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surprising.

It would be worth looking at the query in the Developer Console [Query Plan Tool](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000199003&language=en_US). (That article includes several links about how Salesforce queries are optimised.) In case it made a difference, you could also ask Salesforce support to add an index on `Bar__c`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know about that.  See screenshot above from when I ran the query.  No mention of multiple queries or the same record being counted twice.

Comment: @GeorgeS. Yeah the information presented is pretty limited. Adding the index might kick it out of using "TableScan" and make a difference but definitely "might". A colleague got some good help from salesforce support on a query problem so you could create a case and see if anything useful comes of that.